# How to remove bottom programms bar

Tags: unity

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I've been playing around with compiz settings in compiz settings manager and I messed things up, so in order to go back to default settings I launched as suggested in some threads on this forum:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*
unity --reset
```

My system works now with unity almost the same way as in the beginning. The only difference is that at the bottom I have a bar with all the programs that are currently launched. How can I get rid of this bar?

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and, in the same time, right click with the mouse on that bottom bar, then select **Remove This Panel**.